# CDN Endpoint not working after 24 hrs

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, microsoft-cdn

Since 24 hours my cdn is not working.

We have not changed anything in the portal, and everything reports OK.

How can I troubleshoot this?

http://"storageaccount*.blob.core.windows.net/images/sample.jpg (working)

http://id.vo.msecnd.net/images/sample.jpg (not working).

I did ping ping *id*.vo.msecnd.net to see if it can be resolved and its pinging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your CDN address: http://id.vo.msecnd.net/images/sample.jpg is reporting a 404 error for me. To me this just indicates that the file does not exist at that address.

I would be checking the CDN configuration to ensure nobody else has changed it at all. A couple of points to make on the configuration:

- Make sure your blob container is public (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179354.aspx).
- Validate the CDN endpoint is properly configured (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use-cdn/).